# vue interpolated value not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue JS 2.0 and this is a table I'm trying to display. Everything displays properly initially but when I update(in a method called editPlayerStat) editedPlayers[any-Player-Id], it doesn't update the interpolated value in the respective `small` tag.

At the editPlayerStat() I check to see if editedPlayers[any-Player-Id] is changing properly and it is. But for some reason it isn't getting updated in the `small` tag. Also, in the `span` tag's v-if doesn't update and has the same problem.

While in the same method editPlayerStat(), I manually update `player.stats.month.goals` you see interpolated, to see if also has the same problem and IT DOESN'T. It works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<tr v-if="showMonth" v-for="player in players">
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
  <td><a @click.prevent="editPlayerStat(player._id,'goals',false)" href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
    &nbsp; {{ player.stats.month.goals }} &nbsp;
    <a @click.prevent="editPlayerStat(player._id,'goals',true)" href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
    <span id="changed"> <small>({{ editedPlayers[player._id].stats.goals }})</small></span>
  </td>
  <td><a @click.prevent="editPlayerStat(player._id,'assists',false)" href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
     &nbsp; {{ player.stats.month.assists }} &nbsp;
     <a @click.prevent="editPlayerStat(player._id,'assists',true)" href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
     <span id="changed" v-if="editedPlayers[player._id].stats.assists > 0"> <small>({{ editedPlayers[player._id].stats.assists }})</small></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is my editPlayerStat() method:

```
editPlayerStat(id, type, isIncrease) {
  console.log('editPlayerStat...');
  console.log('editedPlayers[player._id].stats.goals...' + this.editedPlayers[id].stats.goals );
  if(isIncrease) {
    console.log('increase');
    this.editedPlayers[id].stats[type]++;
    this.editedPlayers[id].isEdited = true;
  } else if(!isIncrease && this.editedPlayers[id].stats[type] > 0) {
    console.log('decrease');
    this.editedPlayers[id].stats[type]--;
    this.editedPlayers[id].isEdited = true;
  }
}
```

ANOTHER instance:

I use v-model on an input and display the interpolated value beside and it updates just fine when I update the `input` tag value. But when I 'watch' for changes in the object `player`, the watch function doesn't run except for the first time.

```
<input class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" v-model="player.name">{{ player.name }}


watch: {
    player: function(player) {
      console.log('from watch... '+JSON.stringify(player));
    }
  },
methods: {
  getPlayerInfo() {
    var vm = this;
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/admin/players/info/'+'5847a093a5e13203a4d0455f')
    .then(function (response) {
      vm.player = response.data;
      console.log(response);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(vm.player));
      console.log('showForm: ' + vm.showForm);
   })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
 },
created: {
    this.getPlayerInfo();
  }
```

Output:

```
Object { data: Object, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object, request: XMLHttpRequest }  

{"_id":"5847a093a5e13203a4d0455f","name":"Michael","age":25,"dateOfBirth":"03-04-1998","phone":7987997799,"image":"imgur::djnwkndkjnkn","preferredFoot":"Right","isActive":true,"positions":["CB","RB","RW"]} 

showForm: true  

from watch... {"_id":"5847a093a5e13203a4d0455f","name":"Michael","age":25,"dateOfBirth":"03-04-1998","phone":7987997799,"image":"imgur::djnwkndkjnkn","preferredFoot":"Right","isActive":true,"positions":["CB","RB","RW"]}
```

As you can see, even though the interpolated `player.name` is updated when I edit the value in the `input` tag, the watch function for `player` property doesn't run except for that first time when `player` was initialized with an Object.

Comment: Probably a reactivity issue with the way you are setting the  value. Can you post the edit player code?

Comment: @vbranden I log the editedPlayers[player._id].stats.goals and it shows that it's changing

Comment: yeah, that is typical of a reactivity problem. a console.log will show the updated value but vue does not render the updated value. you are probably either setting a deep property without using Vue.set or encountering one of the "caveats" https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats . i have also had to use setTimeout(fn, 0) if the content renders after the value is set (i.e. modal with transition/animation delay opening)

Comment: @vbranden Yes! I think the 'directly set an item with the index' caveat is what got me. Because I am setting the value directly using the index. I've got this similar problem mentioned above by editing my question, but can't find the solution. Can you tell what's going on?

Comment: You need to use a deep watch for sub properties, this involves setting the watch as an object with a handler function and deep set to true. See c property of example here https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Comment: @vbranden It works! But there's one thing. The `val` and `oldVal` parameters are the same. The new value gets show whether I use `val` or `oldVal`. `handler: function (val, oldVal) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @vbranden Nevermind. I found the issue [here](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/4012/watch-array-mutations-newval-oldval-issue/2).

Comment: @vbranden In the editPlayerStat() method, Instead of `this.editedPlayers[id].stats[type]++`, I use `this.$set(this.editedPlayers.stats[type], id, this.editedPlayers[id].stats[type] + 1);` But it doesn't work. I need to update `stats.goals` (stats is an object with goals property) of the `editedPlayers[]` array. How do I do `this.$set()`? Note: I also did `this.$set(this.editedPlayers[id].stats, type, this.editedPlayers[id].stats[type] + 1);` but to no avail. Also note that this time the value gets updated but doesn't update at all. So yeah, the same problem.

Comment: I don't want to replace the whole object stored in `editedPlayers[id]`, but just `editedPlayers[id].stats.goals` or `stats.whatever`'s value

Comment: I found a similar issue [here](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/119/is-there-a-pretty-way-to-update-object-in-array/6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @vbranden and participants in an issue I raised [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4443). So here's what was going wrong.

I was running into [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) behavior in Vue 2.0, which according to the documentation, *"cannot detect property addition or deletion"*. You will run into this sooner or later.

The thing was that, I was adding properties to an Object directly (or as I thought 'string indexed array' values to an array. Note: also see issue; javascript doesn't allow associative arrays) and Vue couldn't watch for changes in it due to this caveat.

**Solution:** Instead of directly assigning properties to an Object, you need to use Vue.set() or this.$set() to assign them. This allows Vue to track for changes in them.

Original Problem: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/donnyjeremiah/tfvouu61/)

```
editedPlayers: []
this.editedPlayers['someID'] = { name: 'John', stats: { goals: 10, assists: 10 }};
this.editedPlayers['someOtherID'] = { name: 'Flint', stats: { goals: 10, assists: 10 }};
```

Solution: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/donnyjeremiah/tfvouu61/3/)

```
editedPlayers: {}
Vue.set(this.editedPlayers, 'someID', { name: 'John', stats: { goals: 10, assists: 10 }});
Vue.set(this.editedPlayers, 'someOtherID', { name: 'Flint', stats: { goals: 10, assists: 10 }});
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, this helped me two years later!